# Delete sql record with if statement

Tags: t-sql

```
update dbo.tblMessages
set messageFlags = (messageFlags + 1)
where messageId = @messageId
```

So that's the update in my proc. I want to be able to delete the record AFTER the update, IF `messageFlags` becomes '10' after it updates.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `< 10` condition to the WHERE of the UPDATE. If you want to delete when 10 then you are saying "is it 9 now?"

```
-- DECLARE @rc int
update dbo.tblMessages
set
    messageFlags = (messageFlags + 1)
where messageId = @messageId and messageId < 10
/*
or assign SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT to do more stuff first
*/
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    DELETE dbo.tblMessages WHERE messageId = @messageId
```

Or use the assign feature of UPDATE. Similar to the OUTPUT clause

```
DECLARE @newvalue int

BEGIN TRANSACTIOn

update dbo.tblMessages
set
    @newvalue = messageFlags = (messageFlags + 1)
where messageId = @messageId

IF @newvalue = 10
    DELETE dbo.tblMessages WHERE messageId = @messageId

COMMIT TRAN
```

It comes down to the question: do you need the value to actually **be** 10 first before deleting?

Comment: Gotcha. and no it doesn't need to be 10 yet. most likely that would just be performing an unnecessary transaction. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your proc, you could either have it check for the messageFlags value.  If it is going to be 10 (i.e. before the insert happens) then delete it or if you want it after the update happens delete it then (after checking).

You could also use an update trigger to delete it when the value becomes 10.

Comment: I think I want to stay away from triggers but how would I check the value and then do the update./

Comment: Retrieve the current value for that field using a SELECT statement.  And then based on that decide what you actually want to do.  For example, if the value is 9, then you know that + 1 will cause it to go to 10 which then you want to delete it.  So there is no sense in updating the row just to delete it.  Otherwise you would just update the row and not have to worry about deleting it.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score -1):

have you considered CASE statement?
http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlcase.php

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question at hand because they want to delete the record after it becomes 10.  A case statement wouldn't allow them to do this.